# Как создать экземпляр класса, чтобы в консоли выдавало не Object, а название класса?

Tags: javascript

Создаю класс User и экземпляр класса user

```js
class User {
  constructor(username) {
    this.username = username;
  }
}

let user = new User('myUsername');
```

Возникла проблема, что user в консоли отображается, как Object, а не User.

[image: вывод user в консоли]

Хотелось бы, чтобы это было также, как и у объекта document, который является HTMLDocument

[image: вывод document в консоли]

Как такое реализовать?

Comment: Наверное глупый вопрос, но я ввёл ваш код в консоль chrome devtools и вашего результата не получил. Какой консолью вы пользуетесь?

Comment: Я пользуюсь Firefox Nightly

Comment: Это зависит от браузера и его devtools. Никаких стандартов, насколько я знаю, на это нету. Используйте хром, там будет User в консоли.